# How to create an application in j2me, like wallpaper in personalization section in nokia store

Tags: java-me, midlet, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

This is my first day in J2ME,I went through lots of links but I got confuse which is the best way to achieve it.
I want to create an application in J2ME for wallpaper and upload it on personalization  section of nokia store.
I just want best way to do this task,please give me suggestions about it.
I am currently working in Netbean.

Answer (score 0):

programming in j2me requires a prereqiusite of background knowledge in programming. Like knowing what a class, method, return values and others is.
Coming to your question, like which kind of wallpaper app? Just a hint...
J2me tutorial at http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com